# My Video Related evens increase and drop largely in GA4, Why?

Tags: seo, analytics, video-hosting

[image]

So, my website's video events have had big changes lately. Take the video_start event as an example:
starting from Dec 31, it was stable, around 5 to 6K.
Then, the next week (Jan 1 to 7)， it went up to 21K.
It slowly dropped down to 15K in the following 3 weeks.
Then, went back to 5K on Feb 2 and went down to 4K two days later.
And last week (Feb 11 to 18), it became 10K again.
Such up-and-downs happen to Video_progress and video_end events too. Why and should I be worried?

One thing I'm sure, we didn't make any big changes to our website and pages. We have YouTube videos embedded in mostly Product pages and the Home Page. Some blogs have videos but their events are pretty normal. So, it's about Product pages and the Home page.